# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imwrite'

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to make a very minor 2d game engine, and I am trying to get the user to select a file. I am using pygame to write my code, but to choose a file you would need tkinter or make your own file opener and I am to lazy to. I have two problems but i am only going to write my first one here. I have the name and location of the file and when i do `img.imwrite("background.jpg")` it gives me an error, so I thought maybe I'll just run it in a seperate file to test if im writing it right, or it doesn't work, and i still get an error.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
img.imwrite("output.jpg")
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shauryapatel/Desktop/PythonPrograms/GameEngine/player.py", line 3, in <module>
    img.imwrite("output.jpg")
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'imwrite'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't that `cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", img)`?

Comment: @Timus ah sorry, my brain doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imread` returns a numpy array of the image data. `imwrite(filename,image)` (doc [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imwrite-method/amp/?ref=rp)) takes a name and image data, saving it in the specified format. You can't call `imread` as if it were a method of the image data.

Comment: Yeah, sorry... sometimes my brain doesn't work (it never works)